# MongoDB aggregates over row collections of predefined size

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregate

is it possible in MongoDB to perform aggregations over a collection of predefined number of rows, rather than grouping by. For example I want to calculate the average for every 1000 rows, instead of grouping by a certain column.
A smaller example would be the table below, I would like to calculate the Average rating of every 4 consecutive rows:

[image]

So my restult should like somthing like this:

[image]

Below is the input data in JSON:

```js
[{"ItemName":"Item1","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item2","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item2","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item3","Rating":2},
{"ItemName":"Item4","Rating":5},
{"ItemName":"Item5","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item6","Rating":2},
{"ItemName":"Item7","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item8","Rating":1},
{"ItemName":"Item9","Rating":4},
{"ItemName":"Item10","Rating":3},
{"ItemName":"Item11","Rating":2},
{"ItemName":"Item12","Rating":2}]
```

Comment: If you could provide some sample data, sample query and the expected result? That would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @mbuechmann Thanks, please find an example, Hope this can make it easier to explain what we are trying to do.

Comment: Could you post the data as JSON? I do not want to copy the data manually.

Comment: The "Quality" column has not be mentioned before. How to get the average of that is hard to guess.

Comment: The average of the qualti column is actually the value with the biggest count in each of the four rows.

Comment: Ok. But this should be part of your question if you want that solved, too. Otherwise remove it.

Comment: yes you are right, but I am concerned about the part that will allow me to group by number of columns

Comment: Either way: Please edit your answer and include JSON not images. And please only use relevant data.

Comment: @mbuechmann Thanks for your interest and patience, I edited the question to include onlly relevant data and in JSON format. Thanks

Comment: This data is not usable. All items have a rating of 0. They should have the same value as in the image. What you really should do : Replace the image with the data, with the given ratings and format it multi line so that it is readable.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I kept the image just to keep it for reference, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way. You will need to group entire collection into array which may require [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#perform-large-sort-operation-with-external-sort) for large datasets with a huge performance impact.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // count all documents
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        cnt: { $sum: 1},
        docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    } },
    // add _batch field to group documents by
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        docs: { $map: { 
            // add a sequential number to each
            input: { $zip: {
                inputs: [ "$docs",  { $range: [ 0, "$cnt" ] } ]
            } }, 
            as: "doc", 
            in: { $mergeObjects: [ 
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$doc", 0 ] }, 
                // split it in batches by 4 based on the sequential number
                { _batch: { $cond: [ 
                    { $eq: [ { $arrayElemAt: [  "$$doc", 1 ] }, 0 ] }, 
                    1, 
                    { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $arrayElemAt: [  "$$doc", 1 ] }, 4 ] } } 
                ] } }
            ] } 
        } }
    } },    
    { $unwind: "$docs" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } },
    // ensure original order, only if you need ItemRange as a string
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    // calculate averages per batch
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$_batch",
        start: { $first: "$ItemName" }, // only if you need ItemRange as a string
        end: { $last: "$ItemName" }, // only if you need ItemRange as a string
        RatingAvg: {$avg: "$Rating"} 
    } },
    // only if you need them in order
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    // calculate ItemRange, only if you need ItemRange as a string
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ItemRange: { $concat: [ "$start", "-", "$end" ] },
        RatingAvg: 1 
    } },
])
```

Not sure about practical usecase as all averages will change when you remove e.g. the first document.

Anyway if you don't need ItemRange in format "FirstName-LastName" and can live with batch number instead, you can skip 2 lasts in-memory sorts which should improve performance.